# -ear // .war //.POST_MODULE ERROR (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss

I'm in the process of migrating from JBOSS GA 5.1 to JBOSS EAP 6.4 and i have a problem loading the modules, i get this error:

```
Nuevas dependencias que faltan/no satisfechas:
service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations (faltan) dependientes: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations.HandleDelegate, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations.ValidatorFactory, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations.ORB, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations.Validator] 

    11:13:52,045 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014612: Operación ("deploy") falló - dirección: ([("deployment" => "SPM-GUI-ear.ear")]) - descripción de la falla: {
        "JBAS014671: Servicios fallidos" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"SPM-GUI-ear.ear\".\"SPM-GUI.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"SPM-GUI-ear.ear\".\"SPM-GUI.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Error al procesar la fase POST_MODULE de subdeployment \"SPM-GUI.war\" of deployment \"SPM-GUI-ear.ear\"
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/FacesException
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.FacesException from [Module \"deployment.SPM-GUI-ear.ear:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
        "JBAS014771: Servicios con dependencias que faltan/no disponibles" => [
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher.HandleDelegate falta [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher]",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations.ValidatorFactory falta [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations]",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher.ORB falta [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher]",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations.ORB falta [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations]",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher.Validator falta [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher]",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations.Validator falta [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations]",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher.ValidatorFactory falta [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher]",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations.HandleDelegate falta [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations]"
        ]
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
    11:13:52,045 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014612: Operación ("deploy") falló - dirección: ([("deployment" => "SPM-GUI-ear.ear")]) - descripción de la falla: {
        "JBAS014671: Servicios fallidos" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"SPM-GUI-ear.ear\".\"SPM-GUI.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"SPM-GUI-ear.ear\".\"SPM-GUI.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Error al procesar la fase POST_MODULE de subdeployment \"SPM-GUI.war\" of deployment \"SPM-GUI-ear.ear\"
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/FacesException
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.FacesException from [Module \"deployment.SPM-GUI-ear.ear:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
        "JBAS014771: Servicios con dependencias que faltan/no disponibles" => [
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher.HandleDelegate falta [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher]",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations.ValidatorFactory falta [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations]",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher.ORB falta [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher]",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations.ORB falta [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations]",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher.Validator falta [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher]",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations.Validator falta [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations]",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher.ValidatorFactory falta [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher]",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations.HandleDelegate falta [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SPM-GUI-ear.jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations]"
        ]
    }
```

How can I fix that issue?

Comment: Hello, can you please provide a clear title and clarify how we can help you?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing a dependency in your ear or in Jboss.

Add the jar containing javax/faces/FacesException class in your ear.

Two choices :

- in the war : app-web.war/lib
- in the ear : APP-INF\lib

How did you add this library before. In order to help you further you have to tell us how you generate your ear.

You can find it in javax.faces-api but you have to choose the right version for your ear. Example of maven dependency :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```